# Change datetime column in existing column datatime in table in SQL Server

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

This is my column `datetime` that I want to change or copy it:

[first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBPic.jpg)
[image]

When I am copying column and paste, then date is changed to another date.

This is column when copied:

[Second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm9yg.jpg)
[image]

Why is the date changed?

I try to change date to 2018 but automatically changed to 2639 or 2640

Comment: How do you copy it? Where do you paste it?

Comment: copy with ctrl+c and paste in another erecord of same table with ctrl+v

Comment: Directly in SSMS?